# gradle confusion dependency with duplicate sub-project names

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle project with many sub projects and sub-sub projects.   We discovered a weird condition, that goes like this:

Here is an abrievated project structure:

- build.gradle
- settings.gradle
- sub-1

  - common

    - build.gradle
    - src
  - sub-a

    - common

      - build.gradle
      - src
    - war

      - build.gradle
      - src
- sub2

The problem I have is -- the sub  :sub-1:sub-a:war depends on :sub-1:common and :sub-1:sub-a:common and :sub-1:sub-a:war fails to build because some how gradle sees both dependencies but only keeps one, :sub-1:sub-a:common.     Running gradle dependencies will display a line that looks like   :sub-1:common ->  sub-1:sub-a:common

It seems like gradle discards some stuff while computing dependencies or is too clever and sees 2 sub-projects that have the same 'final' name and chooses only one of them in the computed or distilled list of dependencies.

Of course if I rename :sub-1:sub-a:common to :sub-1:sub-a:common1 problem goes away.    FWIW: both the common sub-project make jars -- but they set specific archivesBaseName that are very different.

Short of making sure that all the names of the 'leaf' sub-project are globally unique, is there a way to work around this?

(NOTE:  There maybe degenerate code/project structure patterns going on -- however this is appears in an ant->gradle conversion project where we'll not be changing structue in this 'phase' only the build tool.   While I welcome comments to change struture; I do want to see if there is something I can do with what I have first)

Comment: Issue not resolved, but cause and remedies are a bit more clear.   For the curious [here](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/dependency-substitution-wrong-with-more-than-one-sub-project-with-same-name)  is gradle/forum post about same thing -- but clearer problem description.   And [here](https://github.com/fwelland/Submarine) is a github project that illustrates the condition.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to make the project `group` names unique.

Of course if you need to publish the artifacts from the identical projects this may not be possible. This usually is not the case though, and changing the `group` name resolves the conflict.

```
project(':sub1:common').group = 'sub1.common'
project(':sub1:suba:common').group = 'sub1.suba.common'
```